# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $\emptyset\neq S \subset X$. Show that $diam(S)=\inf\{r>0 : S\subset B_r(x) \forall x\in S\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

The usual definition for the diameter of a nonempty subset of $X$ is 
$diam(S)=\sup\{d(x,y):x,y \in S \}$

Im not sure if I should start with this definition and try to show that the two are equal? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: To show equality it is sometimes useful to show  two inequalities instead, same as proving equality of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h=\inf\{r>0: \forall x\in S(S\subset B_r(x))\}$.

So for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists an $r$, with $h\le r<h+\varepsilon$, such that
$$
S\subset B_r(x), \quad \text{for all $x\in S$.}
$$
Thus, if $z,w\in S$, we have $z\in S\subset B_r(w)$, and hence $d(z,w)<r$, and hence
$$
\mathrm{diam}(S)=\sup\{d(z,w): d,w\in S\}\le r<h+\varepsilon, \quad\text{for all $\varepsilon>0$,}
$$
which implies that 
$$
\mathrm{diam}(S)\le h. \tag{1}
$$
On the other hand, for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $x\in S$,
$$
d(x,w)\le\mathrm{diam}(S), \quad\text{for all $w\in S$}
$$
and hence $w\in B_{\mathrm{diam}(S)+\varepsilon}(x)$, which implies that 
$S\subset B_{\mathrm{diam}(S)+\varepsilon}(x)$. Hence
$$
\mathrm{diam}(S)+\varepsilon\ge \inf\{r>0: \forall x\in S(S\subset B_r(x))\}=h,
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$, and thus
$$
\mathrm{diam}(S)\ge \inf\{r>0: \forall x\in S(S\subset B_r(x))\}=h. \tag{2}
$$
Combination of (1) and (2), provides that
$$
\mathrm{diam}(S)\ge \inf\{r>0: \forall x\in S(S\subset B_r(x))\}.
$$

Comment: doesn't it suppose to be $d(x,w) \le diam(S) + \epsilon$ ? im referring to the line after "on the other hand,.."

Comment: No. The diameter is the supremum, and hence, no $\varepsilon$ necessary.

Comment: Ah. my mistake. thank you.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, but it don't see why you need that $\epsilon$. isn't it true that $w\in B_{diam(S)}(x) $ for all $x \in S$ ?